# AWS Cognito: cross region user pool replication (moving or sharing)

Tags: amazon-cognito

Just came to my attention that there are now more regions supporting Cognito. Is it possible to move a user pool from one region to another?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Cognito, does not replicate ( moving or sharing) the user pools across the regions at the moment, if your users / clients are closer to the region then there will be a minimum propagation delays and users will have a better speed to get the resources from the data center.

If you want to authenticate your users across the region that will be possible by the API they have provided (For example, in javascript sdk you need to mention the region while setting up API for authentication and accessing resources).

Answer (score 0):

For the folks tuning in now , As of June 2020 cognito supports multi-region user pools.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/introducing-multi-region-user-pools/